# TDictionary. Setting a valuetype value while iterating

Tags: delphi, generics

Is there a safe way to mutate the value of a tdictionary, while iterating?

The first naive try:

```
var p: tpair<keytype,valuetype>;

begin
  for p in coll do
    // p.value is readonly for valuetypes and their fields.
 end;
```

failed, and also wrapping the valuetype in a RECORD doesn't help.

Iterating over keys and using dosetvalue might work, but it is private only.

I could of course use a reference type, but that seems a bit silly to me, since the state is an integer. Not elegant.

Added, complete sample:

```
program gendicttest;
//  tests if you can set valuetype key.

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  generics.collections;

type
  TCycleList = tdictionary<integer,integer>; // the value a record type doesn't work either.

var cyclelist :TCycleList;
    p : tpair<integer,integer>;
    j:integer;
begin
  cyclelist:=tcyclelist.Create;
  cyclelist.Add(3,4);
  for  p in cyclelist do
    writeln(p.Key, ' ',p.Value);

  if cyclelist.TryGetValue(3,j) then
    cyclelist.AddOrSetValue(3,j+1);
  for  p in cyclelist do
   p.Value:=0;     // <-- here, and alternative to do this.r

  for  p in cyclelist do
    writeln(p.Key, ' ',p.Value);    
end.
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE], specifically including the definition of coll, keytype and valuetype

Comment: I added the testcode.

Comment: Maybe like `cyclelist.AddOrSetValue(p.Key, 0);`

Comment: That is the only thing I came up with too, but addorsetvalue can add values, invalidating the iterator.  To mutate existing items, addorsetvalue calls the already mentioned dosetvalue, but that one is private.

Comment: Then you can saveguard that with `Contains`. Or maybe just `clyclelist[p.Key] := 0;` because TDictionary has a convenient default indexed property for reading and writing values:  `property Items[const Key: TKey]: TValue read GetItem write SetItem; default;`

Comment: A functional form ( returning ) a tvalue can't be modified if tvalue is a valuetype

Comment: Actually, looking at the source, it seems that the iterator returns a copy of the entry, rather than a pointer to the entry, so even if what you are trying to do were valid, it would not achieve anything.

Comment: Of course it won't work! The pair returned is a copy. So you can at best modify the copy, which makes no sense. This will only work if you enumerate on the keys. But modifying a collection while enumerating it is a very bad thing to do. A good enumerator will fail.

Comment: @Dsm: there are no iterators in Delphi's classes. An iterator could actually be used to modify a collection (but the modification would have to be **through** the iterator, not in some other way). But Delphi uses enumerators, and when enumerating, you should better not modify the underlying class.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thanks - I never really thought of enumerators and iterators as different things, but of course it makes sense.

Comment: Where is this documented? I only found Java docs describing enumerator as an older form of iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it won't work! The pair returned is a copy. So you can at best modify the copy, which makes no sense.

If you only want to clear the values, then get a copy of the keys and enumerate over them to set the value of each key to 0.

```
for var I in cycleList.Keys do
  cycleList.AddOrSetValue(I, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can use Items, which can be indexed with a key:

```
for var I in cycleList.Keys do
  cycleList.Items[I] := 0;
```

*note: can also be done without Rio syntax*

Comment: must... fight ... urge... to ... vote ... everything .... down ... with ... rio ... syntax :) Anyway, that is what I got as closest solution (or class cracker on dosetvalue). I think that the conclusion is that the standard containers and iterator principles are flawed wrt value types.

Comment: Enumerators are not iterators. Enumerators are read-only and they often return a copy. Enumerators are not "flawed" WRT value types, that is their deliberate design. And concerning Rio syntax, I could remove the var and you would probably understand the code too. <g>